# How can a quantum logic gate produce a value other than $0$ or $1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

In classical computation, a bit can have the value of either $1$ or $0$ and one can apply a logic gate to this bit. As far as I understand, in classical computation, no matter what gate is used, the value must still be either $1$ or $0$.

I understand that before measurement, a qubit can exist in a superposition of states, but that once it has been measured, it too must either produce the value of $1$ or $0$.
However, it appears that there are many quantum logic gates that will operate on a qubit and produce a value that is not necessarily $1$ or $0$ (i.e. it the Z gate will change the value of $1$ to $-1$).

So, are we simply changing the basis? Furthermore what is the advantage or having all of these values that a qubit can be in, rather than simply the binary?

Comment: I would say, intuitively, if we regard a simple 'computation step' as a map $S\times G\rightarrow S$, where $S$ is the 'state space' and $G$ is the 'operation space',  an 'algorithm' is then a curve in the state space. With all these values that are not possible in classical computation, we have a larger 'state' space. So we can achieve more complex/efficient  'curves' so that we have a more powerful computation system.

Answer (score 7):

I think you've been fooled by notation. The value inside the $|\rangle$ is a state; a label. The value outside the $|\rangle$ is a weighting; an amplitude. You're negating the *label* instead of the *weight*.

The Z gate doesn't produce a $|-1\rangle$, but it can produce a $-|1\rangle$. Said another way, the Z gate doesn't produce a $|-True\rangle$ but it can turn a $|True\rangle$ into a $-|True\rangle$.

Quantum gates only ever affect the weights.

But that's okay, the state of $n$ qubits is defined by $2^n$ weights. So even simple operations on the qubits are doing *huge* operations on the weights, and when the operation you want happens to line up with those huge operations you can get quite a lot of time savings.

Answer (score 2):

A qubit is in a mixture of the state "0" and the state "1." We write this mixture as $\alpha | 0 \rangle + \beta | 1 \rangle$. Here, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two complex numbers, subject to some constraints. It is not the case that a $Z$ gate will suddenly give us a new state $| - 1 \rangle$ -- the qubit does not possess such a state (it's a qubit, it has two states by definition). Quantum gates act on the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ numbers to perform operations; the $Z$ gate you mention will change $\beta \to - \beta$.

As for "what good are all these extra in-between states" I have to say that it's kind of too broad of a question. Quantum computing and quantum information in general depend on states working this way--I recommend reading more about potential applications of quantum computing and communication to learn about what possibilities are opened by this framework. A technology called "quantum key distribution" can be fairly layman-accessible and relies on the face that a qubit can be put in an indeterminate state.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, I wouldn't use the term mixture for a superposition as mixture already has a very precise meaning.

Comment: I would say, intuitively, if we regard a simple basic 'computation step' as a map S×G→S, where S is the 'state space' and G is the 'operation space', an 'algorithm' is then a curve in the state space. With all these values that are not possible in classical computation, we have a larger 'state' space. So we can achieve more complex/efficient 'curves' to connect an initial state(inputs) with a final state (outputs), so that we have a more powerful computation system. This is why the QC is superior to the classical computers.